# Is there any trick to Resize LVM online that raw by UDEV rule without filesystem?

Tags: oracle, linux, centos, oracle-asm, oracle-grid-control

Here is the Logic Volume for example:

> ```
>    lvcreate   -L2G -n Lv_OraD1 vg_db
>    lvcreate -L180G -n Lv_OraD2 vg_db
>
>    lvdisplay /dev/mapper/Lv_OraD*
> ```

UDEV rule to raw the LV:

> ```
>    vi /etc/udev/rules.d/60-raw.rules
>
>    ACTION=="add", ENV{MAJOR}=="253",ENV{MINOR}=="3", RUN+="/bin/raw /dev/raw/raw1 %N"
>    ACTION=="add", ENV{MAJOR}=="253",ENV{MINOR}=="4", RUN+="/bin/raw /dev/raw/raw2 %N"
>    ACTION=="add",KERNEL=="raw[1-9]",OWNER="grid",GROUP="dba",MODE="660"
>
>    start_udev
>    raw -qa
> ```

ASM Diskgroup maybe like this:

> ```
>    CREATE DISKGROUP DATA1 NORMAL REDUNDANCY  
>    FAILGROUP Fg1 DISK '/dev/raw/raw1' SIZE 2048M ,'/dev/raw/raw2' SIZE 184320M;
> ```

The effect: the size up 2G of DISKGROUP DATA1 cannot be used.

so any tricks to achieve this result online?

> ```
>    lvreduce -L90G /dev/mapper/Lv_OraD2
>    lvextend -L90G /dev/mapper/Lv_OraD1
> ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the disk names and paths:

```
select name, failgroup, path, os_mb, total_mb, free_mb from v$asm_disk;
```

After you found the ASM generated name for the disk you want to shrink, reduce it in ASM to the desired size (I will assume it is called `DATA1_0002`:

```
alter diskgroup data1 resize disk DATA1_0002 size 90G;
```

This starts a rebalance, wait until the rebalance completes, you can view its progress as:

```
select * from v$asm_operation;
```

After the rebalance, run this query again:

```
select name, failgroup, path, os_mb, total_mb, free_mb from v$asm_disk;
```

There you should see the original 184320 `OS_MB`, and 92160 `TOTAL_MB` for the disks you have just shrinked. Next use lvreduce to shrink the LV:

```
lvreduce -L 90G vg_db/Lv_OraD2
```

Make sure you do not reduce the size of LV below the ASM disk size `TOTAL_MB`.

Once it is done, increase the other LV:

```
lvextend -L 90G g_db/Lv_OraD1
```

Go back to ASM, run this again:

```
select name, failgroup, path, os_mb, total_mb, free_mb from v$asm_disk;
```

Here the `OS_MB` for the first disk should increase to 92160, but `TOTAL_MB` still remain 2048.

The final step is to increase the first disk size in ASM:

```
alter diskgroup data1 resize all;
```

The above will resize all ASM disks in the diskgroup up to `OS_MB`. This triggers another short rebalance, and when that finished, you should see 92160 for `OS_MB` and `TOTAL_MB` for both disks.